# Getting Image to stick to bottom

Tags: css

I have a modal that pops up and I'm using the ui-resizable. The problem is if the modal is tall ( it has a set height therefore can have scrolling ), the image travels with the scroll. I can't have it fixed because if you grab it and move horizontally or vertically the modal moves. Not sure what to do. Currently it sits at the bottom right corner of the modal. Can use jQuery too if need be.

https://jsfiddle.net/x7dw1wjg/

HTML

```
 <div class="ui-dialog">
    <div class="container">//contains everything in the modal</div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se">
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 .ui-dialog{
   width: 900px;
   height; auto;
   overflow: auto;
  }
 .ui-resizable-handle {
 width: 22px;
 height: 22px;
 right: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 background-position: -77px -220px; // this is just the icon
 position: absolute;
 }

 .container {
 position: relative;
 padding: 1em;
 overflow: auto;
 width: auto;
 max-width: 900px;
 height: 600px;
 }
```

Comment: Can we get a working example?

Comment: dont have an image but i just used a background-color for an example

Answer (score 0):

```
.container img {
height:0;
width:50%
padding-bottom: 50%;
}
```

This will always make the image square with its height set by it's width.

Comment: this may be true, but it doesn't solve the problem of getting it to stick in the corner of the page. I'm not having a problem with the size of the image. It still scrolls with the page